# Definir se a letra é vogal ou consoante

Tags: javascript, algoritmo, switch

Eu estava a tentar criar um código com JavaScript que após ler a letra introduzida mostrava se era vogal ou consoante mas com qualquer letra que eu coloque o código responde-me que e uma consoante mesmo que seja vogal.

Eu não consigo encontrar o erro no código.

```js
var valorlido
function lerletra() {
    valorlido = prompt("Introduza uma letra")
    return valorlido
}

function isvogal(caracter) {
    switch (caracter) {
        case "a":
        case "A":
        case "e":
        case "E":
        case "i":
        case "I":  
        case "o":
        case "O":
        case "u":
        case "U": 
        break
        return true
        default:
        return false
    }
}

var letra
lerletra ();
if (isvogal(letra) == true) {
    alert("A letra é Vogal")
} else {
    alert("A letra é consoante")
}
```

Comment: Tira o break se tá saindo do switch sem retornar

Comment: coloca o break depois do return

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O código tem vários erros. Um deles é que dá um `break` antes de retornar alguma coisa, então acaba retornando a outra, o `break` tem que ser a última instrução do bloco, mas se você vai dar um `return` nem tem porque usar um `break` porque ele nunca será alcançado.

Não está guardando o valor lido em variável alguma. Eu mantive a variável `letra, mas nem precisava dela.

Fiz algumas outras alterações que podem não afetar o resultado mas que se você acostumar fazer assim poderá ter problemas no futuro, por isso preste atenção em todos os detalhes que eu mudei.

```js
function lerLetra() {
    return prompt("Introduza uma letra");
}

function isVogal(caracter) {
    switch (caracter) {
        case "a":
        case "A":
        case "e":
        case "E":
        case "i":
        case "I":  
        case "o":
        case "O":
        case "u":
        case "U": 
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}

var letra = lerLetra();
if (isVogal(letra)) alert("A letra é vogal");
else alert("A letra é consoante");
```

Eu costumo responder para iniciantes dentro do mesmo algoritmo que a pessoa está fazendo para resolver aquele problema pontual, até porque sem explicação de cada conceito novo a pessoa que está iniciando não entenderá nada do que foi colocado ali. Se o desejo de outra pessoa for conseguir o mesmo resultado de forma mais simples e provavelmente eficiente dá para fazer em uma linha, porque se é para ser simples então faça simples de vez:

```js
alert("aeiouAEIOU".indexOf(prompt("Insira uma letra")) !== -1 ? "A letra é vogal" : "A letra é consoante");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Vowels.js).

Comment: funcionou! obrigado dentro de 8 min eu assinalo como correta a resposta!

Answer (score 13):

Você também consegue resolver seu problema criando um array com as vogais e verificando se o valor digitado no `prompt` se encontra dentro do array, usando a função `indexOf`, dessa forma:

```js
let letra = prompt("Insira uma letra")

let vogais = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

if (vogais.indexOf(letra.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
  alert("Vogal")
} else {
  alert("Consoante")
}
```

Comment: Excelente resposta Gabriel, percebi nas suas respostas a mesma coisa, se o código for reproduzível, faça uma resposta executável, assim aumenta a legibilidade e o conhecimento da sua resposta.

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão, vou me atentar a isso nas próximas vezes.

Comment: Já tinha uma resposta com `indexOf`. Vou apagar a minha.

Answer (score 13):

Você também pode utilizar o método test(), que executa uma busca por uma correspondência entre uma expressão regular e uma string e retorna true ou false.

```js
function isVogal(char) {
    return /^[aeiou]$/.test(char.toLowerCase());
}
alert(isVogal(prompt("Introduza uma letra")) ? "Vogal" : "Consoante");
```

E como o Luiz Felipe comentou abaixo:
Se você usar a flag `i` na expressão regular vai eliminar a necessidade do `toLowerCase`.

```js
function isVogal(char) {
    return /^[aeiou]$/i.test(char);
}
alert(isVogal(prompt("Introduza uma letra")) ? "Vogal" : "Consoante");
```

Comment: Se você usar a flag `i` na expressão regular vai eliminar a necessidade do `toLowerCase`. :)